# Does mongoose uses Wire Protocol by default?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm just reading about MongoDB Wire Protocol but got confused whether mongoose uses it or not by default if not how can we use it with mongoose?

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how exactly mongodb wire prorocol is implemented and how mongoose is using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to communicate directly with a MongoDB server is via the [MongoDB Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/).

Applications use a driver which implements the wire protocol (and in the case of official drivers, are compliant with [standard behaviour specifications](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/specs/)).

Mongoose uses the official [MongoDB Node.js driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). If you want to peek at how Mongoose uses the Node.js driver API, check out the [Mongoose source on GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose).